# How to create CRUD asp.net mvc application without using a database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, crud, dbcontext

I am relatively new to asp.net mvc and Ihave been trying to create a simple CRUD application without using a database and consequently without using DbContext. However, it seems as no feasible. Should I consider DI to address that?

Any ideas would be very welcome.

Comment: This question is not constructive to this Q&A site. You're basically widely asking for *opinions*, without any specific set of requirements (other than "*without using DbContext*", which isn't enough). Please take a look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You will need object persistent framework of some type or can create your own. This can all be done without a database but will use persistent theory.

Really the only way to start doing this is with persistent software programming theory. You would create an object inside an object and inside another object. The objects are stored via an array. You would then need to iterate through the arrays to find the particular item to remove the object from the array.

For example, you would create object of country and then store objects of a state in the country. Then inside of the state array you would store people in another array.

Could create Universe, inside universe would be constellations, and inside constellations would be the star object. All this is stored using arrays.

To save the state you would store all this to a bin file using serializable class that that country array would read to restart the state of all the objects. I have wrote software like this for desktop applications in VB.

I am thinking you would do the same thing using C# and simply create your objects.

Is this the type of thing you had in mind?

This same theory can be used instead of using cookies to track a users progress on a site, but seems like most people just use a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a static dictionary if you want to do this just for learning purposes,

note you'll loose all the data on app stop,

here's a tutorial for asp.net mvc basics which does a bit of crud at the end without DB: http://youtu.be/fsfOFL4bXXA